# How to set a value in 1 table according to the count of a value in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

The database I am using (It is in a relationship with table 1):

[image: The Database i am using]
[Sample Data for Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzHgd.png)

I want to set Present Count in Accounts according to the number of 'P' characters in Table1.Attendance (Right now, it is manually set). I tried making a 'Counting' query that looks like this

```
UPDATE Accounts SET [Present Count] = (SELECT Count(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Attendance = 'P')
WHERE Accounts.Username = Table1.Username
```

I tried this too

```
SELECT Count(Table1.Attendance) AS PCount HAVING ((Count(Table1.Attendance))='P'), Count(Table1.Attendance) AS ACount HAVING (Count(Table1.Attendance))='A'
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Username
```

But this won't work, giving no error, no update or anything
This as well:

```
UPDATE Accounts
SET [Present Count] = (SELECT Count(*)
                       FROM Table1
                       WHERE Table1.Attendance = 'P' AND
                             Accounts.Username = Table1.Username
                      );
```

This displays the count i have set in the table manually, not the count calculated from the total number of 'P's

Comment: Add sample data please.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a inner join on the subquery for count group by username

```
UPDATE A
SET A.[Present Count] = t.my_count
FROM Accounts AS A
INNER JOIN  (
  SELECT username, Count(*) AS my_count
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE Table1.Attendance = 'P'
  GROUP BY username
) AS t ON A.Username = t.Username
```

Comment: do i have to create a 'my_count' field first in Table1? If so, how do i have different counts for different usernames?

Comment: my_count is an alias from subqiry  .. and the related   join clause  ..  join different username between the two tables  so you have  the right username count associated  tp the username  in accounts ..and the set value assigne the corresponding result

Comment: It is giving me a syntax error 'missing operator' at FROM on line 3

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE Accounts
    SET [Present Count] = (SELECT Count(*)
                           FROM Table1
                           WHERE Table1.Attendance = 'P' AND
                                 Accounts.Username = Table1.Username
                          );
```

EDIT:

What values does this return?

```
SELECT UserName, Count(*)
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.Attendance = 'P' 
GROUP BY Username
```

Perhaps what you see as `'P'` isn't really `'P'` and you are just getting `0` for everything because nothing matches.

Comment: I checked and this query displays the manually set values for the Present Count. I want them to be counted out and have their corresponding usernames displayed beside them

Comment: @HyperBrid . . . This query doesn't display anything.  It should fix the errors in your `update` query.

Comment: It doesn't change the counts when i run it